# (mysql) IBD files randomly deleted on WEMP stack?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, nginx

Yesterday I ran into a weird problem: IBD file was suddenly missing.

Got it fixed by importing database dump and re-creating table for the missing part.

Everything was fine for a while until another table/ibd file went missing.

What could causes this kind of behaviour? It is seems like it always hits on tables that have prefix cache_. Can it be a PHP script or is this more MySQL related?

Comment: Sounds like your DB files are located is the same folder as php files and their cached versions, check your configs and make sure each component has its own folder.

Comment: DB files and PHP scripts are in different folders. I couldn't get this setup to work and files got deleted occasionally. I believe that it was most likely some kind of bug either in MariaDB(latest release) or in the WEMP stack itself. Now I've installed WNMP and it works flawlessly (it is also very simple to configure and administrate, recommend).